# Module is not available only in Safari

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out why myApp.adverts module is not available only on Safari. I used angular-seed to start a project. Everything works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'myApp.homepage',
  'myApp.adverts',
  'myApp.version'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('homepage');
}]);
```

homepage/homepage.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.homepage', ['ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('homepage', {
    url:         '/homepage',
    templateUrl: 'homepage/homepage.html',
    controller:  'HomepageCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('HomepageCtrl', [function() {
}]);
```

adverts/adverts.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.adverts', ['ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('adverts', {
    url:         '/adverts',
    templateUrl: 'adverts/adverts.html',
    controller:  'AdvertsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('AdvertsCtrl', [function() {
}]);
```

index.html

```
...
<div ui-view></div>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="homepage/homepage.js"></script>
<script src="adverts/adverts.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: Try loading app.js after adverts.js in index.html

Comment: @fluoresce I've already tried that and the same error still shows up.

Comment: @gradle I've got exactly the same problem, module which doesn't load on safari only, chrome, firefox and IE doesn't have any problem. Did you find a solution?